# Regex Using dynamic named subpattern?

Tags: regex

I am doing something like this to prepare a dynamic regex.

```
$mapping = "asa/user/{u}/d/{d}/{f}"; //line 1
$mapper = preg_replace('/\{.*?\}/m','(\w+)',str_replace('/','#',$mapping));     //line 2     
preg_match("/".$mapper."/",str_replace('/','#',$input),$arr);
print_r($arr);
```

which give output like this for $input = /asa/user/ZZA/d/asasa/gh

```
Array ( [0] => asa#user#ZZA#d#asasa#gh [1] => ZZA [2] => asasa [3] => gh )
```

What I want is to get something like this.

```
 Array ( [u] => ZZA [d] => asasa [f] => gh )
```

I know I can do this with using ?P, so trying this

```
 $mapper = preg_replace('/\{.*?\}/m','(?P<name>\w+)',str_replace('/','#',$mapping));
```

Which obviously would not work as it will use same index name for all params,what i need to do is replace name with u,d,f dynamically.
i can do this with explode i believe, then traversing the array and replace one by one. But is there any better solution to do this type of operation?

At line 2 can read value between braces and then use it as index to replace with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At line 2 can read value between braces and then use it as index to
>   replace with?

Yes, by *capturing groups **()*** and *backrefrences **$n***.

You should change the second line to:

```
$mapper = preg_replace('/\{(.*?)\}/m','(?P<$1>\w+)', str_replace('/','#',$mapping));
```

Which results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => asa#user#ZZA#d#asasa#gh
    [u] => ZZA
    [1] => ZZA
    [d] => asasa
    [2] => asasa
    [f] => gh
    [3] => gh
)
```